# Categorical and numerical features in Spark MlLib (Java)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am working with Apache Spark MlLib version 2.11 in Java. I need to pass to the RandomForestClassifier both categorical and numerical features (strings and numbers).

What is the best API to use for such a case? An example would be very helpful.

**Edit**

I tried to use the VectorIndexer, but it accepts only numbers and I couldn't understand how to integrate OneHotEncoder to it. Also, I it's not clear how to tell which features are categorical and which are numerical. Where do I need to set all possible categories?

Here is some code I tried:

```
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {
        new StructField("label", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
        new StructField("features", new ArrayType(DataTypes.StringType, false), false,
                Metadata.empty()),
});

JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = trainingData.map(record -> {
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String field : fields) {
        values.add(record.get(field));
    }
    return RowFactory.create(record.get(Constants.GROUND_TRUTH), values.toArray(new String[0]));
});

Dataset<Row> trainingDataDataframe = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);

StringIndexerModel labelIndexer = new StringIndexer()
        .setInputCol("label")
        .setOutputCol("indexedLabel")
        .fit(trainingDataDataframe);

OneHotEncoder encoder = new OneHotEncoder()
        .setInputCol("features")
        .setOutputCol("featuresVec");
Dataset<Row> encoded = encoder.transform(trainingDataDataframe);

VectorIndexerModel featureIndexer = new VectorIndexer()
        .setInputCol("featuresVec")
        .setOutputCol("indexedFeatures")
        .setMaxCategories(maxCategories)
        .fit(encoded);

StringIndexerModel featureIndexer = new StringIndexer()
        .setInputCol("features")
        .setOutputCol("indexedFeatures")
        .fit(encoded);

RandomForestClassifier rf = new RandomForestClassifier();
        .setNumTrees(numTrees);
        .setFeatureSubsetStrategy(featureSubsetStrategy);
        .setImpurity(impurity);
        .setMaxDepth(maxDepth);
        .setMaxBins(maxBins);
        .setSeed(seed)
        .setLabelCol("indexedLabel")
        .setFeaturesCol("indexedFeatures");

IndexToString labelConverter = new IndexToString()
        .setInputCol("prediction")
        .setOutputCol("predictedLabel")
        .setLabels(labelIndexer.labels());

Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline()
        .setStages(new PipelineStage[] {labelIndexer, featureIndexer, rf, labelConverter});

PipelineModel model = pipeline.fit(encoded);
```

Comment: That answer is in scala but you've asked for an API. And the API is the same.

Comment: The question referenced is about spark-ml, and not spark-mllib. Furthermore, it shows how to handle a feature as categorical, and not how to use both categorical and numerical features together. Please reconsider un-marking the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to the issue. I upgraded the version of Spark MlLib to 2.3.0. In this version they included a class named OneHotEncoderEstimator. It has an input of all the categorical columns (Doubles) and outputs the respective vectors.

Then I used the VectorAssembler class to unify all the features (numerical and categorical) into one vector, which I sent to the RandomForestClassifier.

Answer (score 2):

A Random Forest, like a Decision Tree, does not need One Hot encoding to manage categorical features, it is one of the few techniques that can manage categorical features natively (that is, without a transformation to binary features, that is the purpose of one hot encoding).

The easiest way to deal with continuous and categorical features at the same time is to set the  `maxCategories` parameter properly. When you'll train your forest, the distinct values of each feature will be count, and columns with less than `maxCategories` distinct values in the training data will be considered categorical.

You can check that the feature is categorical by printing the tree/forest, with  `toDebugString`. If it's categorical you will see something like  `if feature0 in {0,1,2}` instead of the usual  `<=`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but maxCategories is a bit problematic, because I may have more categories than numbers in the numerical features, so, in this case, the numerical features will be treated as categorical.

I actually succeded to build the model, please refer to the answer I posted.